# How to redirect old permalinks with regex?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, permalinks

I am trying to solve an issue with link rot that is a result from a permalink change a year ago on a high traffic site. I know you can redirect certain permalink structures in apache but how is this done in regex?

I need to move all link request  that are in this format:

```
http://www.*****.com/permalinks/year/month/day/title
```

to this current (as of 2015) format:

```
http: //www.*****.com/year/month/day/title
```

Basically I just need to remove the name permalinks from the url request to fetch it from the database.

I tried forcing a search on anything with a 404 but it has not been reliable, along with it being very slow since the database is large.

I tried this in regex but it does not work:

```
/permalinks/(d*)/(d*)/(d*)/(.*) => /(d*)/(d*)/(d*)$4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I will look into that code. It appears to be for nginx.conf? I do not have access to that at the moment so I can't try it.

I went with this regular expression through the urban giraffe redirection plugin and it works:

/permalinks/(.*) ==> /$1

Answer (score 0):

You need simple regex rewrite for remove permalinks/ and keep rest of url:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     example.com;
        rewrite ^/permalinks/(.*)  http://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```